# contact form become doesn't work and won't show error message

Tags: laravel

I made Laravel contact form project a year ago and it worked perfectly. I haven't  use it. And today I put  same this project at rental web server(same server and same plan)but it doesn't work. and It won't show any error message.

First problem is about validation. 
At my local(I use XAMPP)I can go next page which is confirm.blade.php. however I deploy at my real server and I fill up all info at text field and click submit. but the page refreshing really quick and doesn't go next page which is confirm.blade.php. Could someone gime me a direction please?

Laravel Framework is 5.7.28

**UPDATE**

FORM CODE

```
@extends('layouts.default_mail')
@section('title', 'test')
@section('content')

<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="{{url('/mail')}}">
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{csrf_token()}}">{{-- CSRF対策--}}


  <!--↓↓件名↓↓-->
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name" class="control-label col-sm-2">Name</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10 @if($errors->has('name')) has-error @endif">
    <input type="text" name="name" id="title" value="{{ old('name') }}" class="form-control" placeholder="" autofocus>
    @if($errors->has('name'))
     <p class="text-danger" style="margin-bottom: 30px;">{{ $errors->first('name') }}</p>
    @endif
    <!--/.col-sm-10--></div>
  <!--/.form-group--></div>
  <!--↑↑件名↑↑-->



  <!--↓↓メールアドレス↓↓-->
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email" class="control-label col-sm-2">Email:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10 @if($errors->has('email')) has-error @endif">
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Type Email address" value="{{ old('email') }}" autofocus>
    @if($errors->has('email'))
     <p class="text-danger" style="margin-bottom: 30px;">{{ $errors->first('email') }}</p>
    @endif
    <!--/.col-sm-10--></div>
  <!--/.form-group--></div>
  <!--↑↑メールアドレス↑↑-->

  <!--↓↓本文↓↓-->
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="body" class="control-label col-sm-2">body</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10 @if($errors->has('body')) has-error @endif">
    <textarea class="form-control" name="body" id="body" rows="3" placeholder="messages" autofocus>{{ old('body') }}</textarea>


    <!--/.col-sm-10--></div>
  <!--/.form-group--></div>
  <!--↑↑本文↑↑-->

  <!--↓↓time and order number ↓↓-->

<input type="hidden" name="sno" class="form-control" value="{{ date('YmdHis') }}">
<input type="hidden" name="time" class="form-control" value="{{ date('Y-m-d H:i:s') }}">


  <!--↑↑time and order number ↑↑-->



  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">submit</button>
    </div>
    <!--/form-group--></div>

</form>
@endsection
```

Is this deploy and routing problem? but it worked a year ago and I didn't change any code...I update head of 1st page which is  index.blade.php

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="{{url('/mail')}}">
```

and here is .env file

```
APP_URL=http://localhost
```

Everyone. Thank you.

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Mail;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Contact;

class MailController extends Controller
{

    public function index(){
      return view('mail.index');
    }

public function confirm(Request $request)
{
   $rules = [   
    'name' => 'required',
    'hp' => 'required',
    'email' => 'required|email'    
  ];

    $this->validate($request, $rules); 
    $data = $request->all(); 

    // setting session key value for you data
    $request->session()->put('data',$data);

// DEBUG
 Log::debug('$data="'.$data.'"');
 Log::debug('$request="'.$request.'"');


    return view('mail.confirm', compact("data"));
}

/*
 *　complete page 
 */
public function complete(Request $request)
 { 

   $data = $request->session()->pull('data');


   $token = array_shift($data);


   $Contact = Contact::create($data);



      Mail::send(['text' => 'mail.temp'], $data, function($message) use($data){
        $message->to($data["email"])->bcc('11223344@yahoo.co.jp')->from('2233@sunshine.online')->subject('Thank you。');});


      Mail::send(['text' => 'mail.admintemp'], $data, function($message) use($data){
        $message->to('2233@sunshine.online')->from('1122@sunshine.online')->subject('u got mail');});


    $data = session()->regenerateToken();
    return view('mail.complete');
}

}
```

Here is table info

```
CREATE TABLE `contact` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `hp` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `sec` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `body` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `sno` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `time` timestamp NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

And here is model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Contact extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
use EncryptsAttributes;
protected $encrypts = [
        'name',        
        'hp',
        'email',
        'body'
];

    protected $fillable = [     
        'name',
        'title',
        'sec',
        'hp',
        'email',
        'body'];

}
```

Comment: "_but the page won't go next page_" It stays on the same page and doesn't submit? What form? Nothing in the server logs?

Comment: Dear @kerbholz Thank you for answering me.  Yes. I fill up all text field then click submit but the page doesn't go second page.  And About log I update my code . I wrote like this but I still couldn't get error and log.

Comment: Can we see the code for your form too, please?

Comment: Dear @kerbholz Thank you for answering me. I update  index.blade.php code. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Change This:

$this->validate($request, $rules);

To:

request()->validate($rules);

Comment: Dear @Deepesh Thank you for helping me. I tried your code but still same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you.

```
$request->validate([
        'name' => 'required',
        'hp' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email'
]);
```

Comment: Dear @anthony-shoshi-gomes Thank you. but still same. I update some what I've been working. I hope it help you.

Comment: @greeniron If your server is Linux server make sure all file name is exactly same as you create. Linux server is case sensitive where Xampp doesn't.

Comment: Dear @anthony-shoshi-gomes  Thank you for comment. The server is FreeBSD Yeah... I did double check.